# pydicom: dcm_read specific_taglist argument creates attribute error

Tags: python, list, attributes, pydicom

I have a tree of four subjects and their DICOM images. Here is an example of one subject's directory structure:

```
'C:\\DICOM_EXPORT\\four_de-id\\four_de-id\\100013\\100013\\*.dcm*'
```

I'm creating a loop where I recursively go through

`C:\\DICOM_EXPORT\\four_de-id\\four_de-id\\`

in each of the four subject's folder and recursively select the one .dcm file, then apply `pydicom.dcmread()` on that image and populate an initialized dictionary `dcm_read` with subject ID `subject[38:44]` as a key and the contents of specific DCM tags as each key's respective value. The tags are in a list I have created called `TAGS` (see below).

```
>>> print(TAGS)
['(0008,0008)', '(0008,0020)', '(0008,0060)', '(0008,0070)', '(0008,0080)', '(0008,0081)', '(0008,0090)', '(0008,009C)', '(0008,1010)', '(0008,1030)', '(0008,103E)', '(0008,1040)', '(0008,1090)', '(0010,1010)', '(0018,0050)', '(0018,0080)', '(0018,0081)', '(0018,0082)', '(0018,0087)', '(0018,0088)', '(0018,0089)', '(0018,0093)', '(0018,0094)', '(0018,1000)', '(0018,1020)', '(0018,1030)', '(0018,1250)', '(0018,1251)', '(0018,9041)', '(0018,9050)', '(0020,0011)', '(0020,0035)', '(0020,0037)', '(0028,0010)', '(0028,0011)', '(0028,0012)', '(0028,0030)']


dcm_read = {}

for i in subjects:
    os.chdir(i)
    dcm_image=glob.glob('*.dcm')
    for subject in subjects:
        dcm_read.update({subject[38:44]:pydicom.dcmread(fp=dcm_image, specific_tags=TAGS)})
```

The `specific_tags` argument from `pydicom.dcmread()` seems to be where the error (see below) arises.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 5, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Isabel Wingert\Anaconda3\envs\DCM_EXPORT\lib\site-packages\pydicom\filereader.py", line 850, in dcmread
    force=force, specific_tags=specific_tags)
  File "C:\Users\Isabel Wingert\Anaconda3\envs\DCM_EXPORT\lib\site-packages\pydicom\filereader.py", line 651, in read_partial
    preamble = read_preamble(fileobj, force)
  File "C:\Users\Isabel Wingert\Anaconda3\envs\DCM_EXPORT\lib\site-packages\pydicom\filereader.py", line 589, in read_preamble
    preamble = fp.read(128)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'read'
```

However, `pydicom`'s [documentation](https://pydicom.github.io/pydicom/stable/ref_guide.html) states that the argument for `specific_taglist` could be a list of elements. Has anyone ever run into this issue? Or do I have to set up my `TAGS` list differently?

Answer (score 1):

`glob.glob('*.dcm')` returns a list, but `pydicom.dcmread` expects a path for the `fp` argument.

If you expect only one .dcm file in the directory then you can fix your issue with indexing the list of .dcm files returned by `glob.glob`:

```
dcm_read.update({subject[38:44]:pydicom.dcmread(fp=dcm_image[0], specific_tags=TAGS)})
```

Comment: +it's-yer-boy-chet see my post down below for an update. Couldn't post in a comment.

Comment: Yeah, that's a different error, now your issue is the tag list `TAGS`.  From the documentation (which seems to be for a different version of `pydicom` than you have) the tag list should be  a list of ints.  You have a list of strings, none of which can be cast as ints, so that might be the issue.

Comment: I got it, I had to create a list of the keywords rather than the tags.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in subjects:
    os.chdir(i)
    dcm_image=glob.glob('*.dcm')
    for subject in subjects:
          path=str(subject+"\\"+dcm_image[0])
          dcm_read.update({subject[38:44]:pydicom.dcmread(fp=path, specific_tags=TAGS)})
```

I took it's-yer-boy-chet's suggestion by adding the `path` variable, then setting that as the `fp` argument. but now a type error occurs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 6, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Isabel Wingert\Anaconda3\envs\DCM_EXPORT\lib\site-packages\pydicom\filereader.py", line 850, in dcmread
    force=force, specific_tags=specific_tags)
  File "C:\Users\Isabel Wingert\Anaconda3\envs\DCM_EXPORT\lib\site-packages\pydicom\filereader.py", line 728, in read_partial
    specific_tags=specific_tags)
  File "C:\Users\Isabel Wingert\Anaconda3\envs\DCM_EXPORT\lib\site-packages\pydicom\filereader.py", line 363, in read_dataset
    raw_data_element = next(de_gen)
  File "C:\Users\Isabel Wingert\Anaconda3\envs\DCM_EXPORT\lib\site-packages\pydicom\filereader.py", line 117, in data_element_generator
    tag = Tag(tag_for_keyword(tag))
  File "C:\Users\Isabel Wingert\Anaconda3\envs\DCM_EXPORT\lib\site-packages\pydicom\tag.py", line 114, in Tag
    if long_value > 0xFFFFFFFF:
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'
```